# NPM command not working in vscode terminal for tailwindcss

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, tailwind-css

I just migrated to ubuntu as my main OS for web development. I installed VScode and copied my projects. When I run the npm run build or watch command for tailwindcss, I get the following error:

```
> ecommerce-product-page-main@1.0.0 build
  > tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./css/main.css

/home/dev-aldo/Documents/Dev Folder/All Works/ecommerce-product-page-main/node_modules/yaml/dist/compose/composer.js:33
                if (prelude[i + 1]?.[0] !== '#')
                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev-aldo/Documents/Dev Folder/All Works/ecommerce-product-page-main/node_modules/yaml/dist/index.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

I have installed rebuilt npm but  still get the error. I am very new to ubuntu so please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by reinstalling tailwind:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
```